# Django send_mail not working and returns 0 errors

Tags: python, django

My code executes fine from my localhost. However, when I try and run my django program from an ubuntu 16.04 server it doesn't work. I tried running the program in the shell and it doesn't return any errors. When I check my inbox I don't receive an email from the "from" address.

I've tried sending the email to different addresses. I've also tried sending it using TLS instead of SSL. I also tried using smtplib to send the email instead of using django's send_mail.

Here is my code I'm using to send the email

`send_mail('subject','my message','from_email@gmail.com',['to_email@xxxx.com'],fail_silently=False)`

Here is my settings.py file

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'from_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

Comment: Don't use Gmail in production. Use a mail service that's actually designed for automated / programmatic use. Sendgrid, Mailgun, Amazon SES, etc.

Comment: Thank you after switching to Amazon SES it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple settings that Django/Gmail require. Make sure to define EMAIL_BACKEND.

Additionally for port 465 you need to enable SSL which is disabled by default.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#email-use-ssl

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'from_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Alternatively you can use TLS on 587

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'from_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues I encountered when using Gmail is that Gmail blocked the website from accessing it because the IP address was unrecognized and Gmail thought that someone had broken into my account.

Have you checked your account for alerts you may need to deal with? We spent hours before doing that ourselves.